# "Login error using xxx account."

Tags: grammaticality

This is a summary of an error message. The author is trying to convey the meaning that something went wrong while trying to log in using a specific account.

Is this phrase, not sure it is a sentence, grammatically correct? If not, why not? If yes, how can it be improved? It does sound a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fine. Computer messages aiming at being straight-forward and programmers not bothering to make long sentences, it should be short in order to be efficient. 
"There's been an error while logging in with xxx account" would be an acceptable rephrasing but again, not useful.